# How can i know if someone has opened an email in WordPress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, tracking, status

To know the email has been opened or not, I am using the SMTP mailer in WordPress cms. The email is sending but the issue is that when I open the email, the email status in dB are not updating.

Email send page code:

```
$track_code = md5(rand());                   
$mail->Subject = 'You have a new quote';

$message .='<img src="https://oqdemo.com/quotesystem/wp-admin/admin.php?page=track.php&track_code='.$track_code.'" style="width:1px;height:1px;">';
$message .='<h1>Hello,'.$cust_name.'</h1>';
```

Comment: Basically i am developing this system in wordpress using smtp

Comment: You don't seem to show us anything that is actually noticing that that tracker pixel has been downloaded. What are you using for that? I guess you are also aware that users can turn tracking off in their browsers and that some browsers set some sort of level which ignores tracking.